# USB ports stopped working on Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: usb, 20.04, usb-drive

USB ports stopped working after I booted my laptop and have not worked even after doing several reboots. Nothing is being detected but it charges my phone with a usb cord. I am new to Linux in general.

HP 15 Notebook
Product Number: G1V01UA#ABA

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I'm not sure what to do as my pendrive gets warm when connected but my pc does not recognize it.

Comment: Hey Reuben Prosper! What do you exactly mean by "*stopped working*"? Are you able to connect any pendrive and see its files? Open terminal, paste this: `lsusb` and press Enter. Copy the output and paste it **in your question** (*not in the comments*).

Comment: Please mention the laptop name and model number **in the question**. Also, does the computer recognise the pendrive? Is the issue with one port or both the ports?

Comment: @technastic_tc Also had same problem on desktop. Ran update. Rebooted. Suddenly `lsusb` says I have USB drives -- but when plug in to them nothing happens. Of note keyboard doesn't work. Switched ports. Tried reinstall `xserver`. No joy. Have old PS/2 keyboard typing on now. Interesting to see I'm not the only one with problems this update.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be:

> Bug in kernel 5.4.0-44 and 0-45 so far. External keyboard or dropping down to kernel 5.4.0-42 works in recovery mode. – crip659 Sep 13 at 21:05

per: [Ubuntu 20.04 - keyboard not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274890/ubuntu-20-04-keyboard-not-working)

In my fix attempts I'd inadvertantly deleted old kernels but can reinstall by:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic
```