# Compaq laptop keyboard not working

Tags: boot, 20.04, system-installation, kernel, keyboard

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop a few days ago. Previously the laptop had Windows 8.

While installing I was using an external keyboard. Now my inbuilt keyboard is not working; even the lights on capslock button etc are not working. It's not even working while booting. I am new to Ubuntu so I don't know where to start solving this problem.

Comment: keyboard not working at boot time ... "cool", you are in tablet mode! :-(  Just try if one of these can help:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585681/ubuntu-20-04-upgrades-breaks-keyboard-mouse/763179#763179

Answer (score -1):

Try this. https://techwiser.com/fix-keyboard-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04/ . If it doesn't work, you have to reinstall the OS as suggested here https://appuals.com/fix-ubuntu-20-04-lts-keyboard-and-mouse-not-working/ . It could be that the keyboard is not working because you had an external keyboard connected during the installation process. So you need to reinstall the OS.

Try to look also here [Ubuntu 20.04 - keyboard not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274890/ubuntu-20-04-keyboard-not-working)

Comment: Thank you for replying. But to reinstall i need keyboard to work and its not even working while booting up ..in that case what i need to do?   And once again thanks for replying..

Comment: do you have an external keyboard? if so, just do the steps in the first link provided. Even if you don't there is a procedure you can follow by just using the mouse. Again, read and try to do the method(s) of the first link.

Comment: reinstalling OS? No, may turn out useless and workaround should come easier. Try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585681/ubuntu-20-04-upgrades-breaks-keyboard-mouse/763179#763179  Have success!