# How to edit .conf files when only the touch keyboard is working?

Tags: 22.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, touchscreen

I set up a dual boot with my new laptop with touchscreen functionality. I'm having the same problem described in this thread:

[Ubuntu 20.04 - keyboard not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274890/ubuntu-20-04-keyboard-not-working)

Essentially, it's a bug in the new kernels that causes Ubuntu to assume that some laptops with touchscreen capabilities are a tablet. Because of this, although the keyboard doesn't work, the onscreen keyboard does still work and can be used in the terminal albeit with limited capacity (there aren't any special key functions like ctrl, alt, etc. on the touch keyboard).

The solution in that thread has people edit the .conf file but I can't figure out how to save the file without using special keys (ctrl in particular); I can navigate to and edit the file just fine but I can't figure out how to save it. Any ideas?

Edit: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a Windows 11 machine.

Comment: Apologies; wrong tag.  I'm dual booting Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a Windows 11 machine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you can access the terminal, start a root shell:

```
sudo -i
```

Then run:

```
cat > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-intel_vbtn.conf <<EOF
# bug in module breaks keyboard, so don't load it
blacklist intel_vbtn
EOF
```

The entire thing can be done without using any special key other than <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I don't know if the on-screen keyboard lets you type a `#`. If it doesn't then just omit the comment.  If it doesn't support entering `<`, `>`, `_` or `/`, then copy-paste the whole thing to the terminal; that should still work.

Comment: Great, that worked like a charm!